# Pandas DataFrame) one column replace other df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, concatenation

I have **two pandas DataFrame**

```
# python 3
one is | A | B | C | and another is | D | E | F |
       |---|---|---|                |---|---|---|
       | 1 | 2 | 3 |                | 3 | 4 | 6 |
       | 4 | 5 | 6 |                | 8 | 7 | 9 |
       | ......... |                | ......... |
```

I want to get '**expected**' result

```
expected result : 

       | A | D | E | F | C |               
       |---|---|---|---|---|               
       | 1 | 3 | 4 | 6 | 3 |               
       | 4 | 8 | 7 | 9 | 6 |               
       | ................. |
        
df1['B'] convert into df2
```

**I have tried**

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1, sort=False)

and drop column df['B']
```

**but it doesn't seem to be very efficient.
Could it be solved by using insert() or another method?**

Comment: why do you think it is not efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your method is good, also you can remove column before `concat`:

```
pd.concat([df1.drop('B', axis=1),df2], axis=1, sort=False)
```

Another method with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1.drop('B', axis=1).join(df2)
```

Comment: I am going to try it as the first method of your good suggestions! Thank you so much and I hope you finish the year well